# ruby / sort an array of hashes from a defined index

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

Having the following array, it defines the sorting :

```
[300, 450, 345, 23]
```

And the following array, unsorted :

```
[
  {id: 450, title: 'rand1'},
  {id: 23, title: 'rand3'},
  {id: 300, title: 'rand0'},
  {id: 345, title: 'rand2'},
]
```

I'd like the first array to be a "rule" to sort my second array (probably by matching the id key).

How can i get achieve this cleanly ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Naïve approach:

```
sorter = [300, 450, 345, 23]
input = [
   {id: 450, title: 'rand1'},  
   {id: 23, title: 'rand3'},  
   {id: 300, title: 'rand0'},  
   {id: 345, title: 'rand2'},  
]  
input.sort do |h1, h2|
  sorter.index(h1[:id]) <=> sorter.index(h2[:id])
end
#⇒ [
#     {:id=>300, :title=>"rand0"},
#     {:id=>450, :title=>"rand1"},
#     {:id=>345, :title=>"rand2"},
#     {:id=>23, :title=>"rand3"}]
```

or even simper:

```
input.sort_by { |h| sorter.index(h[:id]) }
```

Comment: in case you know this one @mudasowba https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49150665/ruby-avoid-errors-when-nil-in-sort-by