# Ruby / avoid errors when nil in sort_by

Tags: arrays, ruby

[From this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49028373/102133) (@mudasobwa);

```
input.sort_by { |h| sorter.index(h[:id]) }
```

In some unfortunate cases; `sorter.index(h[:id])` returns nil, it then returns an error

How would one cleanly avoid such error to happen, while having the rest of the array sorted ?

Comment: Add `|| -1` if you want them at the start or `|| sorter.size` if you want them at the end.

Comment: Or better add `|| -Float::INFINITY`.

Comment: what does || -Float::INFINITY would do compared to the two others ? adds it at the beginning ?

Comment: `-Float::INFINITY` will do the same as `-1`. You can put it as an alternative to the index. Aka `sorter.index(h[:id]) || -Float::INFINITY`.

Comment: ok thx a lot guys

Comment: Yes, to the beginning. To add to the end use `+Float::INFINITY`. It’s not so complicated to check it yourself: `[1,2,nil].sort_by { |e| e || -Float::INFINITY }` ⇒ `[nil, 1, 2]`.

Comment: i'm on it yep; thx again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
input.sort_by { |h| [sorter.index(h[:id]) ? 1 : 0, sorter.index(h[:id])] }
```

This will take all values, sort them by whether they have a sorter.index(h[:id]) available initially, and then sort those with that value by that value